# PHP classes misunderstandings

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to make a CMS and I'm stuck using classes in PHP.

I have this little connection class and I don't know why it's not working. It's giving me the this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\Users\eha\Desktop\Carlos' Stuff\xampp\htdocs\test\layout\system\class.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\Users\eha\Desktop\Carlos' Stuff\xampp\htdocs\test\layout\system\class.php on line 4

```
class server_connect {
    function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {
        $this->$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
        if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                    . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }
    protected $mysqli = NULL;
    protected function set_connection(&$serverconnect){
        $this->$mysqli = $serverconnect;
    }   
}

class site_manager extends server_connect {
```

ok now I get the syntax for that now when calling a parent element $mysqli Im doing parent::$mysqli and its telling me that its a undeclared variable

```
class site_manager extends server_connect {
function __construct(&$conect){
    parent::set_connection($conect);
}
public function getContent($page , $sub){   
    if($page == 'home' || ($page != 'home' && $sub ==NULL))
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM public WHERE section = ?";
    else
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM public WHERE section = ? AND subsection = ?";
    $stmt = parent::$mysqli->stmt_init();
```

Comment: That should be `$this->mysqli` throughout. You don't need the second `$` when referring to an object's attributes.

Comment: Don't need, and in fact can't have.  Unless you've defined the local variable `$mysqli`, `$this->$mysqli` effectively becomes `$this->{null}`, or `$this->{''}`.  You only need the second `$` when you're using a variable's value as a property name.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to access the instance variables you need to do so like this:

```
$this->mysqli
```

You are doing this

```
$this->$mysqli
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few problems: First, you're using `$this->$variable`; it should be `$this->variable`. Secondly, on one line you use `$this->$mysqli` and then the next line you omit the `$this->`, writing `$mysqli`. You need to retain `$this->`; in the scope of a method, `$this->variable` and `$variable` are two different variables.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your OOP writing is wrong. you need to use `$this->mysqli` instead of `$this->$mysqli`

The full code fix:

```
class server_connect {
protected $mysqli = NULL;
    function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Connect Error (' . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
                    . $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }
    protected function set_connection(&$serverconnect){
        $this->mysqli = $serverconnect;
    }   
}

class site_manager extends server_connect {
```

Comment: is it the same thing for the parent:: op? like when calling the $mysqli parent::$mysqli vs parent::mysqli

Comment: public function getContent($page , $sub){ 
  if($page == 'home' || ($page != 'home' && $sub ==NULL))
   $qry = "SELECT * FROM public WHERE section = ?";
  else
   $qry = "SELECT * FROM public WHERE section = ? AND subsection = ?";
  $stmt = parent::$mysqli->stmt_init();

Comment: @CarlosArturoAlaniz: `parent::$mysqli` should be `$this->mysqli`.  (You can, and typically should, use `public` and `protected` members of the base class just like they're members of yours.  The main difference is you don't have to define them, cause the base class already did.)  The only time you might need to do something different is if you add your own stuff that uses the same name as something in the parent class.